# Widget not saving in admin side when inline css is called

Tags: wordpress, widget

My Widget content is ,

```
<div style="padding-right: 20%;">
  <div class="foot_address">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</div>

  <div style="width: 100%; height: 1px; background: #b2b2b2;"></div>
  [divider height="15"]

  +91 123456678

  <div style="width: 100%; height: 1px; background: #b2b2b2;"></div>
  [divider height="15"]

  info@example.com

  <div style="width: 100%; height: 1px; background: #b2b2b2;"></div>
  [divider height="15"]

<div>
```

When i'm removing the div classes and styles the widget is saving , but not with the present data .

It is perfectly working in localhost , the issue raised when moved to the live server.

Comment: in which browser you are testing?, and are you under intranet ?

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to have started with WordPress 4.8. Maybe with localhost, you got a older version and that is the reason it works there.

One solution is to use a [Classic Text Widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-text-widget/) plugin which adds a widget that allows HTML code. Just be aware that this plugin uses PHP namespaces which are only supported in PHP Version 5.3.0 and higher.